# ng-Mask for String manipulation

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, autoresizingmask

I am trying to convert/only allowing the Mask defined value in the input.
lets say - uppercase. `Mask code 'A' regEx : [A-Z]`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" mask="AAAA">
```

**expecting only [A-Z] uppercase character with range is 4 (ABCD).**
But the above-mentioned code is neither converting to uppercase nor restricting to type lowercase.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the user input and show the characters in upper case then may be you can create a directive to achieve that behavior.

For example -

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[char-mask]'
})
export class CharDirective {
  @Input() upperCase = true;

  @HostBinding('class.upper')
  get upper() {
    return this.upperCase;
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydown(e) {
    if (!this.validateKeyCode(e.keyCode, e.target.value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  private validateKeyCode(keyCode: number, value: string): boolean {
    var inp = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    if ((/[a-zA-Z]/.test(inp)) && (value.length <= 3)) {
      return true;
    }
    const whiteListedCodes = [8, 9, 13, 16, 37, 39];
    if (whiteListedCodes.indexOf(keyCode) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

and  use than on the input where the behavior is desired.

```
<input class="form-control" char-mask />
```

For implementation you can refer - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-char-only-mask?file=src/app/char-mask.ts

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Your solution will disable other keys like for example "backspace"

Comment: @xplo4d, you are correct, with earlier implementation key like backspace didn't work. I have modified the implementation and answer as well to consider these keys which we need. We can add those keys in whiteListedCodes array

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a solution I found, if you are using ng-Mask which is the third party library.**

mask code 'A' contents = > letters (uppercase or lowercase) and digits.
but if you look for the regex it doesn't contain any digits.thats why Mask with code 'A' will take input as a number also.

and there is no specific predefined mask for upper and lower case.
so we have to go for the custom mask, this like.

```
markup :
 <input type="text" class="form-control" mask="AAAA" [patterns]="customPatterns">

component: 
 customPatterns: any = {'A': { pattern: new RegExp('\[A-Z0-9\]')}};
```

this is just a way to do it. regex pattern can be different as per requirement.

please have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/uppercase-ng-mask
any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using the pattern attribute? This will restrict it to A-Z, the browser will say the pattern is not correct after submitting.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Z]{4}">
```

Comment: No, I am already using ngMask, so the pattern is taken care of by third party (ng-mask). for a few default types of regex, they have introduced few codes, like regex [A-Z]  code is A/S .this solution isn't fit. Thanks for the response.